# Legacy GCE and GKE metadata requests from google_daemon/manage_addresses.py

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an old Debian Compute Engine instance (created and running since December 2013) and got an email warning about the turndown of Legacy GCE and GKE metadata server endpoints (more details at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server).

I followed the directions for locating the process and found that the requests were coming from `/usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_addresses.py`. The script seems to be the same as what's at https://github.com/gtt116/gce/blob/master/google_daemon/manage_addresses.py (also with what's in that directory).

I don't recall installing this, so I'm imaging it came with the provided Debian image I used in 2013.

Does anyone know what this `manage_addresses.py` script is, what it does, and what I should do with it now that the legacy metadata server endpoints are turning down? Is it safe to just stop running it? Or is there a new script I should replace it with? Or should I just try to update it myself to use the new endpoint?

Comment: What OS Level is the Debian OS?  It may be that you have to think about your instance as a custom image.  In which case you have to install the guest environment see ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment

This also has a comment which reads: If the guest environment is available on your instance but is outdated, update the guest environment.

And there is a link to proceed.

Comment: Yes you are correct! It seems that the old guest environment never got updated. Manually installing the guest environment from scratch seemed to fix this (and it seemed to remove the old guest environment too). I posted some more details in an answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I dug around and was able to trace `/usr/share/google/google_daemon/manage_addresses.py` as being installed by a package called `google-compute-daemon`. A search for that brought me to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#troubleshooting which explains that `google-compute-daemon` has been replaced with `python-google-compute-engine`. That led me to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment . I followed the instructions there and manually installed the guest environment.

I noticed during installation that it said it was removing the `google-compute-daemon` package (and a packaged called `google-startup-scripts`), so this seems like the right thing. And I'm no longer seeing any requests to the legacy endpoints. So it seems like at some point the old guest environment failed to update.

TLDR; If you have this problem, follow the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#installing_guest_environment to manually update the guest environment.